# how can we invoke an ADFS2.0 identity provider from an ADFS 2.0 service provider?

Tags: java, adfs

the situation is my entire app is developed in java and the customer wants us to authenticate the users using ADFS 2.0 with SAML protocol.

I have a code where i have used java SOAP call to authenticate user against ADFS but with WS-Fed protocol.
However, things are different when it gets to ADFS with SAML.

I was planning to have an ADFS server on my side to act as a Service Provider that will be invoked from java which would then authenticate the user against client ADFS 2.0 IDP

However, I am not sure whether this configuration can be achieved. Can it be?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are asking - are you wanting to use ADFS as a bridge?

Yes - you can go from RP --> WS-Fed --> ADFS RP --> SAML --> ADFS IDP

but typically this is via browser redirects.

Or you could just use Spring security and go SAML direct.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the prompt response. Yes, i am looking for an ADFS bridge but sounds like i have to handle majority of chunk in my code compared to SAML direct or shibboleth ?

Comment: ADFS is an RP here - just like shibboleth. It should be the same amount of code either way.

Comment: Thanks for the insight.I appreciate it.